# Is there a way to create a method in javascript class just to create variables?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I avoid same line of code `const myObject = this._getMyObject();` from multiple methods?

I have a method `_getMyObject()` in a class which returns an `Object[]`. I am using it in various other methods `const myObject = this._getMyObject();`
Is there a way to create a method or something which return my variable `const myObject = this._getMyObject();` that I can call in other methods?

```
export default class MyClass {
    _getMyObject() {
        //   some code
    }
    _getMySecondObject() {
        //   some code
    }

    _methodOne() {
        const myObject = this._getMyObject();
        const mySecondObject = this._getMySecondObject();
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
    _methodTwo() {
        const myObject = this._getMyObject();
        const mySecondObject = this._getMySecondObject();
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
    _methodThird() {
        const myObject = this._getMyObject();
        const mySecondObject = this._getMySecondObject();
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
}
```

Thanks ritaj for solving my problem:

```
    _getLengthOfBoth() {
        const myObject = this._getMyObject();
        const mySecondObject = this._getMySecondObject();
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        return lengthOfBoth;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question. Could you give an example of how would you like it to work?

Comment: why not make `myObject` a field, then you can access it simply by `this.myObject`. Also, you can `myObject` a getter which will behave the same way as a field and you can put code that'll run each time you call the getter.

Comment: Why don't you just `const lengthOfBoth = this._getMyObject().length + this._getMySecondObject().length;` You already have "a method or something which return my variable". It's ` _getMyObject()`.

Comment: `const myObject = this._getMyObject();` isn't exactly long. Anything you replace this with is going to be just as complex, etc. So this seems pretty pointless? What do you hope to achieve here exactly?

Comment: @Aioros I would like not to repeat same three statement in each method.

Comment: @ritaj is there a way I don't need to repeat `const lengthOfBoth = this._getMyObject().length + this._getMySecondObject().length;` in each method? Is it possible to define lengthOfBoth outside each method and just call `lengthOfBoth` in each method?

Comment: Sure. `_getLengthOfBoth() {
        const myObject = this._getMyObject();
        const mySecondObject = this._getMySecondObject();
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        return lengthOfBoth;
    }`

Comment: I think your taking "don't repeat yourself" a little too literally

Comment: Do you just want the syntax improvement?  What if you have to do some extra binding at the cost of performance to achieve your syntax goals?  Would that be OK?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is even related to your question but you could try this:

```js
const obj1 = (src) => src._getMyObject();
const obj2 = (src) => src._getMySecondObject();


export default class MyClass {
    _getMyObject() {
        //   some code
    }
    _getMySecondObject() {
        //   some code
    }

    _methodOne() {
        const myObject = obj1(this);
        const mySecondObject = obj2(this);
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
    _methodTwo() {
        const myObject = obj1(this);
        const mySecondObject = obj2(this);
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
    _methodThird() {
        const myObject = obj1(this);
        const mySecondObject = obj2(this);
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
}
```

This is fewer characters to type and `obj1` and `obj2` can minify, if that matters to you.

You could even go a step further and create pseudo private functions for your class instead of using an underline.

```js
const getMyObject = (src) => {
  // The code that used to be in MyClass._getMyObject()
};
const getMySecondObject = (src) => {
  // The code that used to be in MyClass._getMySecondObject()
};


export default class MyClass {
    _methodOne() {
        const myObject = getMyObject(this);
        const mySecondObject = getMySecondObject(this);
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
    _methodTwo() {
        const myObject = getMyObject(this);
        const mySecondObject = getMySecondObject(this);
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
    _methodThird() {
        const myObject = getMyObject(this);
        const mySecondObject = getMySecondObject(this);
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
}
```

Or even like this:

```js
const getMyObject = () => {
  // `this` === the object just like when it was a function of the object
  // The code that used to be in MyClass._getMyObject()
};
const getMySecondObject = () => {
  // `this` === the object just like when it was a function of the object
  // The code that used to be in MyClass._getMySecondObject()
};


export default class MyClass {
    _methodOne() {
        const myObject = getMyObject.bind(this)();
        const mySecondObject = getMySecondObject.bind(this)();
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
    _methodTwo() {
        const myObject = getMyObject.bind(this)();
        const mySecondObject = getMySecondObject.bind(this)();
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
    _methodThird() {
        const myObject = getMyObject.bind(this)();
        const mySecondObject = getMySecondObject.bind(this)();
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
}
```

In this example, thanks to `bind(this)` you are creating true private function for the instance for the class and each call to `getMyObject` and `getMySecondObject` will have the appropriate `this` value.

One other option would be to use destructuring:

```js
const getMyObjects = () => {
  // `this` === the object just like when it was a function of the object
  // The code that used to be in
  // MyClass._getMyObject() and  MyClass._getMySecondObject()
  
  return {myObject, mySecondObject};
};


export default class MyClass {
    _methodOne() {
        const {myObject, mySecondObject} = getMyObjects.bind(this)();
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
    _methodTwo() {
        const {myObject, mySecondObject} = getMyObjects.bind(this)();
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
    _methodThird() {
        const {myObject, mySecondObject} = getMyObjects.bind(this)();
        const lengthOfBoth = myObject.length + mySecondObject.length;
        //some code
    }
}
```

This allows a single function to do the work that used to be in `_getMyObject` and `_getMySecondObject` and return the two answers in a single object. The results of the object are destructured and place into the two variables `myObject` and `mySecondObject`.

*UPDATE*:

Sorry. I had written:

`const myObject = getMyObject.bind(this);` when I should have written `const myObject = getMyObject.bind(this)();`

That has been fixed.

Answer (score -1):

use the constructor

```
export default class MyClass {
constructor(){
  this.myObject = this._getMyObject();
  this.mySecondObject = this._getMySecondObject();
}

_getMyObject() {
    //   some code
}
_getMySecondObject() {
    //   some code
}

_methodOne() {
    const lengthOfBoth = this.myObject.length + this.mySecondObject.length;
    //some code
}
_methodTwo() {
    const lengthOfBoth = this.myObject.length + this.mySecondObject.length;
    //some code
}
_methodThird() {
    const lengthOfBoth = this.myObject.length + this.mySecondObject.length;
    //some code
}
}
```